# how to detect and notify user of message from server?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

app sent transaction to the server, user closes app, now a message needs to be
sent back to the phone from the server 10+ minutes later. The phone may be asleep, or the user might be checking his email. The question which I have is:

1. how can the phone be notified that a message has been received from server ?
2. how to display that message ?

A possible solution would be Google cloud messaging, but I still am not able to answer these 2 questions

Comment: Do you aware of android services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have to use SERVICE for that.

2) And to show that message.

Do like this.

The variable and method are members of Service class:

```
public final static String ACTION = "com.apps.example.MainActivity";

private void messageFromServer()//this method sends broadcast messages
 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MOVEMENT_UPDATE);
    String messageFromServer=serverMessage //here you will put server message
    intent.putExtra("MessageFromServer", messageFromServer);

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And this are the methods from Main activity:

You have to register receiver in the onResume method:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{   

    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    intentFilter= new IntentFilter(YourService.ACTION);
    messageFromServer= new MessageFromServer();
    registerReceiver(messageFromServer, intentFilter);


    startYourService();

    super.onResume();
}

private void startYourService()
{
    startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
}

public class MessageFromServer extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

            // this method receives broadcast messages. 

            // Be sure to modify AndroidManifest.xml file in 
            // order to enable message receiving

        String messageFromServer = intent.getStringExtra("MessageFromServer");

        updateGUI();// here you can update the ui
    }
}
```

and put service in you manifest file.

```
 <service android:name="com.apps.service.YourService" ></service>
```

Comment: should this be a sticky broadcast ?